# Using httr package, setting a header where the header name is a variable

Tags: r, httr

I want to set a header in an request using the R httr package and set a header, when I have the name of the header in a variable.

I would like to do something like this:

```
tokenName = 'X-Auth-Token'

get_credentials_test <- function (token) {

  url <- paste(baseUrl,"/api/usercredentials", sep = '')
  r <- GET(url, add_headers(tokenName = token))
  r
}
```

however, the above code seems to set a header with the name tokenName.

It does work if I do the following:

```
get_credentials_test <- function (token) {

   url <- paste(baseUrl,"/api/usercredentials", sep = '')
   r <- GET(url, add_headers('X-Auth-Token' = token))
   r
}
```

but I want to have some flexibility if the name of the header changes and the requirement to add the header is sprinkled liberally around the code.  I am not sure if it is possible to add a header contained with a variable but that is what I would like to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could create the headers as a named vector, and then pass it as the `.headers` argument:

```
h <- c(token)
names(h) <- tokenName

r <- GET(url, add_headers(.headers = h))
```

While this works because `add_headers` takes a `.headers` argument ([see here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/httr/docs/add_headers)), a more general alternative for calling a function with arbitrary argument names is `do.call`:

```
h <- list(token)
names(h) <- tokenName

r <- GET(url, do.call(add_headers, h))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with `structure()`:

```
get_creds <- function(base.url, path, header.name, token) {
    url <- paste0(base.url, path)
    header <- structure(token, names = header.name)
    r <- httr::GET(url, httr::add_headers(header))
    r
}
```